# Arrays assignment before/after declaring type

Tags: c++

Assignment at the same line I declared the type, returns no errors and compiles correctly at the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    char c[5] = "Hey!"; 
}
```

But the following doesn't compile, because as we know, array assignment is not possible in c++.

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    char c[5]; 
    c = "Hey!"; //ERROR: expression must be a modifiable lvalue.
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: And question is?

Comment: Arrays can't be assigned to. `char c[5] = "Hey!"` works because it's an *initialziation*, not an assignment.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat noted! thanks

Comment: Just do `char c[] = "Hey!";` - Get the compiler to do the counting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between initialization and assignment. In the second example what you want to do is not initialization, but assignment. But such assignment to array is not possible in C++.

You can only do multiple assignment of the array, when you declare the array:

```
char c[5] = "Hey!";
```

is equivalent to

```
char c[5] = {'H', 'e', 'y', '!', '\0'};
```

After declaration, you'll have to assign each value individually, i.e.

```
c[0] = 'H';
c[1] = 'e';
c[2] = 'y';
c[3] = '!';
c[4] = '\0';
```

Alternatively you could use an STL container, in this case (array of characters) `std::string` is appropriate:

```
std::string c;
c = "Hey!;
```

Comment: Another issue, if I do `char name[20];` and then `name = { 's', 'h' };` compiler gives two errors, the same error on this question and another one saying _too many initializer values_

Comment: Well as I said you can't assign an initializing list like this. You either have to do it when declaring or then element by element.. Or use an STL container